# Texturing a Triangle Strip with glTexCoord2f()?

Tags: java, opengl, rendering

I recently finished my seedbased heightmap generator and try now to add a texture to my generated terrain. First i implemented the texture rendering to my old TerrainRenderer, which used GL_TRIANGLES for drawing.

This works very well with my test texture:

[image: This works very well with my test texture.]

Here is my old Rendering Code:

```
for(int z = 0; z < terrain.terrainSizeZ-1; z++) {
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES);
    for(int x = 0; x < terrain.terrainSizeX-1; x++) {
       GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
       GL11.glVertex3f(x*size, terrain.terrain[x][z], z*size);
       GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
       GL11.glVertex3f(x*size, terrain.terrain[x][z+1], (z+1)*size);
       GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
       GL11.glVertex3f((x+1)*size, terrain.terrain[x+1][z], (z)*size);
       GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
       GL11.glVertex3f((x+1)*(size), terrain.terrain[x+1][z], z*size);
       GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
       GL11.glVertex3f(x*size, terrain.terrain[x][z+1], (z+1)*size);
       GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
       GL11.glVertex3f((x+1)*size, terrain.terrain[x+1][z+1],  (z+1)*size);
    }
    GL11.glEnd();
}
```

Then I rewrote my renderer and used GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP for a big FPS boost. The raw terrain is rendering perfectly.

So i also tried to add texturing, but i can not figure out how to calculate the texture coords for the trianglestrips. It does not matter what i do, always, at least one texture is not rotating correctly. (So, seamless textures may not work very good)

Here you see what i mean:

[image: Here you see what i mean]

Here is my new rendering code:

```
private static void render() {
    [...]
    for(int z = 0; z < terrain.terrainSizeZ-1; z++) {
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

        for(int x = 0; x < terrain.terrainSizeX-1; x++) {
            nextTextureCoord();
            GL11.glVertex3f(x*size, terrain.terrain[x][z], z*size);
            nextTextureCoord();
            GL11.glVertex3f(x*size, terrain.terrain[x][z+1], (z+1)*size);
        }

        clearTextureCoord();
        GL11.glEnd();
    }
    [...]
}

private static int texCoord = 0;
private static void nextTextureCoord() {
    if(texCoord == 0)
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    else if(texCoord == 1)  
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    else if(texCoord == 2)
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    else if(texCoord == 3)  
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);

    if(texCoord < 3)
        texCoord++;
    else
        texCoord = 0;
}

private static void clearTextureCoord() {
    texCoord = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the tiling feature of texture coordinates:

```
// ...
for(int x = 0; x < terrain.terrainSizeX-1; x++) {
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(x, z);
    GL11.glVertex3f(x*size, terrain.terrain[x][z], z*size);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(x, z + 1);
    GL11.glVertex3f(x*size, terrain.terrain[x][z+1], (z+1)*size);
}
// ...
```

In the default sampler configuration, texture coordinates above 1 wrap around, resulting in a tiling of the texture.

Btw, if your project is not too big already, I would strongly recommend abandoning deprecated functionality like `glTextCoord2f(), glVertex3f()`, etc and switch to modern OpenGL.